# Why does dir of a module show no __dict__? (python)

Tags: python, dictionary, module, dir

For example:

```
>>> import os
>>> '__dict__' in dir(os)
False
```

But `os.__dict__` shows there is a `__dict__` attribute.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because `dir` uses a [specialized implementation](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/30b3798782f1/Objects/object.c#l1829) for modules, which returns all the keys in the module's `__dict__`, and thus neglects to include the `__dict__` attribute itself.

It is not clear from reading the source code whether this is intentional.

Comment: @RamchandraApte I think everything is a bug to you... :)) You've been reporting bugs everywhere

Comment: @alKid I've been a bit active on the Python bug tracker but not so much, especially in recent times.